# What is @ in Sqlparameter objName = new Sqlparameter ("@jobfolder", SqlDbType.Text)

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is **@** in `Sqlparameter objName = new Sqlparameter ("@jobfolder", SqlDbType.Text)`

Comment: In SqlParameter objName = new Sqlparameter ("@jobfolder", SqlDbType.Text), the "@" is optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@` is just sql server's way of identifying parameters (variables)

The SQL you are running will look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE
WHERE MYCOLUMN = @jobfolder
```

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL the `@` sign it perpended to variables to identify them as such.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953.aspx) (Transact-SQL Variables, under Declaring a Transact-SQL Variable):

```
The DECLARE statement initializes a Transact-SQL variable by: 

 - Assigning a name. The name must have a single @ as the first character.
 - Assigning a system-supplied or user-defined data type and a length. For numeric variables, a precision and scale are also assigned. For variables of type XML, an optional schema collection may be assigned.
 - Setting the value to NULL.
```

The variable name you pass in through your code should match the one in the stored procedure/prepared statement, hence is also needs the `@`.

Answer (score 0):

Required first character of a SQL Server parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

THank you. I also found this information online based on your answer "As you may know, ADO provides two ways to supply a stored procedure
with parameter values. In the first method, you refer to the parameter
name directly and simply assign a value. In the second, you build
a Parameter object from scratch and add it to the Command object's
Parameters collection.

Be aware, though, that when using named parameters, you must supply
the @ character, which precedes every SQL Server parameter name,
like so:

cmd.Parameters("@someParam") = 250

On the other hand, when you build the Parameter object from scratch,
you don't need to supply the @ charcter, as seen here:

Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("someParam", adBigInt, adParamInput, 2, 250)
cmd.Parameters.Append param"